# How to conditionally host a hotspot on a dietpi, when no known Access Points are available

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi-hotspot

i am having a raspberry provisioned with dietpi.

**Background:**
This Pi is used as a magic mirror and about to be a gift for a friend. It uses wifi only. The mirror will be delivered with a known wpa_supplicant.conf file to have it working from the first day.
The use case is, in case he changes the WPA-Key or has a different SSID he should be able to ssh into the pi.

**Goal**
The overall goal is having a script that regularly checks for available network (network connectivity to Access Point (AP) would be sufficient).

My current issue is that i cannot create a Hotspot at all.

(Working): So if connectivity is given, the configuration is just using dhcp as a client.

(Not Working): If no connectivity is given, configuration on the pi should be changed to host an AP, provide a dhcp server for its subnet. (alternatives ideas welcome)

While i dug into the documentation i figured out that dietpi is not working with `dnsmasq` but `isc-dchp-server`.

All my used services are started and no `journalctl -xe` entries are worrying.

`$systemctl list-units --type=service` Looks fine

Enabling AP from `dietpi-config` does not look like how i configured it, as it is using the wrong subnet. (should be 42.xx instead of 1.xx)

```
[  OK  ] DietPi-Config | Desired setting in /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf was already set: wpa_passphrase=SECRET_PHRASE
[  OK  ] DietPi-WiFiDB | mkdir -p /etc/wpa_supplicant
[  OK  ] DietPi-WiFiDB | eval > /var/lib/dietpi/dietpi-wifi.db
[ INFO ] DietPi-WiFiDB | Applied WiFi DB slot 0 with SSID "CLEARNET"
[ INFO ] DietPi-WiFiDB | Applied WiFi DB slot 1 with SSID ""
[ INFO ] DietPi-WiFiDB | Applied WiFi DB slot 2 with SSID ""
[ INFO ] DietPi-WiFiDB | Applied WiFi DB slot 3 with SSID ""
[ INFO ] DietPi-WiFiDB | Applied WiFi DB slot 4 with SSID ""
[  OK  ] DietPi-WiFiDB | chown root:root /var/lib/dietpi/dietpi-wifi.db /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
[  OK  ] DietPi-WiFiDB | chmod 600 /var/lib/dietpi/dietpi-wifi.db /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
[  OK  ] DietPi-Config | systemctl stop isc-dhcp-server
[ SUB1 ] DietPi-Set_hardware > wifimodules (enable)
[ INFO ] DietPi-Set_hardware | Please wait, enabling WiFi modules...
[ INFO ] DietPi-Set_hardware | Checking for required APT packages: iw wireless-tools wpasupplicant wireless-regdb
[  OK  ] wifimodules enable | Completed
[ INFO ] DietPi-Config | Dropping network connections, please wait...
[ INFO ] DietPi-Config | Restarting network connections, please wait...
[  OK  ] DietPi-Config | systemctl daemon-reload
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:23:f0:44
Sending on   LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:23:f0:44
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.169 from 192.168.1.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.169 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.169 from 192.168.1.1
bound to 192.168.1.169 -- renewal in 18890 seconds.
[  OK  ] DietPi-Config | systemctl start isc-dhcp-server
[ INFO ] DietPi-Config | Reloading networking data, please wait...
[  OK  ] DietPi-Config | Network restarted
```

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# Location: /etc/network/interfaces
# Please modify network settings via: dietpi-config
# Or create your own drop-ins in: /etc/network/interfaces.d/

# Drop-in configs
source interfaces.d/*

# Ethernet
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
#dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1

# WiFi
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.0.1
#dns-nameservers 9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112
pre-up iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
post-down iw dev "wlan0 set power_save on

# iptables NAT rules
up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
up ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv6.nat
```

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.42.99
  network 192.168.42.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.42.255
  wpa-ssid "magic-mirror"
  wpa-psk "SECRET_PHRASE"
  wpa-group TKIP CCMP
  wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
```

```
$cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.42.10 192.168.42.50;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.42.255;
        option routers 192.168.42.1;
        option domain-name "local";
        option domain-name-servers 9.9.9.9, 149.112.112.112;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice